# pip install PyEngine 3D issue in windows 10

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I am running `PY 3.7` in windows 10, got `pip install Pygame` alright , but can't `pip install PyEngine3D`

Gives me this error,

> ERROR: Cannot unpack file
> C:\Users\rbnrg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-fcu82867**PyEngine3D**
> (downloaded from
> C:\Users\rbnrg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-02kvvwsw)

i tried inserting in path and `pip install` from URL from zip, from GitHub, I've tried by Power Shell too. I'm still trying. But i wish there's a `Wheel` for `PyEngine3D`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Git Installed Please run these commands:

1. git clone https://github.com/ubuntunux/PyEngine3D
2. cd PyEngine3D
3. pip install -r requirements.txt
4. python main.py

If you dont have git Installed Please visit this website- https://github.com/ubuntunux/PyEngine3D

1. Then Click on Code(Green Button) and Download Zip.
2. Unzip the file.
3. Open Cmd and Navigate into that folder you unzipped.
4. Then execute these commands-

   pip install -r requirements.txt

   python main.py

Comment: Thanks ,yes i got Git Hub Desktop gives me an option to clone it from there i think , I'm gonna try , thanks

Comment: Got it nicely and easy , i took instructions from both blocks of here your first  answer , see in first paragraph the pip coding to main.py its not complete so in second paragraph it is , and worked , though i had to use the " local path " given before closing the wizard, luckily i saved it , its on atm , stuck in piglet scene not responding but surely will , like a black canvas .  thanks i had days trying

Comment: Please mark this as answer if this solves your problem.